# chrome extension - execute a content script without refreshing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to execute a content script only at github pull request tab.

I've tried:

```
{
    ...,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://github.com/*/pulls"], // Only for pull request tab
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

But **it does not work** when I move from a tab to a tab in the same page. (ex. code -> issue -> pull request -> ...) If I refresh at pull request page, it works.

**I want to execute the `content.js` whenever I enter pull request tab(`*://github.com/*/pulls`) even if I do not refresh.**

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: It's a dynamically updated page. You need to listen to DOM events issued by the page or use webNavigation API in the background/event page. See [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you I'll check it out!